# How do I create a column with two values (or names) at a given weight in R

Tags: r, random, shapefile, dbf

I'm trying to create a column in my data in .dbf.
I need to create a column in which 70% is 0 (or TRUE) and 30% is 1 (or FALSE), only at random.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need for example 100 values, try this:

```r
sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This way builds on the response from @Leonardo

This way helps you create a dataframe with 2 columns and a header.

1. One column with your data
2. Another column with False or True, where False == 30%, True == 70%

First create data frame and column

```
df <- sample(c(0,1), size = 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))

column_1 <- "Column 1"
```

Combine the two to create dataframe

```
newdf <- data.frame("Column 1" = df)
```

finally, using the `grepl` command, we can fill in a column, with False and True

```
newdf$presence <- ""
newdf$abesence <-"1"
newdf$presence[grepl('1', newdf$abesence)] <- ifelse(newdf$Column.1[grepl('1', newdf$abesence)] == 1,'False', 'True')
```

Get rid of unnecessary column

```
newdf[3] <- NULL
```

check the frequency of False and True

```
table(newdf$presence)
```

And there ya go! It's not the most elegant way of going about this, but it works :)